# Merge a count query & fetch query into one & let MySQL do the work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm currently encountering a problem with false validations on the return of my function. & I've narrowed it down to the following line:

```
if ($User_ID === null){
   return false;
}
```

Now, i'm performing some queries using MySQLi;

```
$Query = $this->_Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password,Salt,UserStatus FROM users WHERE Username=?");
$Query->bind_param('s',$Username);
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($User_ID,$Username,$User_Password,$User_Salt,$User_Status);
$Query->fetch();
$Query->close();
```

After fetching, I noticed that if there is no data detected from the queries, the bound results will return a null instead of actual data, but the problem is sometimes this isn't working for some reason as it allows access to the members area because of some type of validation being seen wrong from the code, i'm guessing it's the `return` statements either false or an array. So to tweak the performance and want to attempt to remove the `NULL` check.

Standard procedure for what i've currently implemented is as follows:

```
$User_Chk = $this->_Database->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM users WHERE `username`=?");
$User_Chk->bind_param('s',$Username);
$User_Chk->execute();
$User_Chk->bind_result($Count);
$User_Chk->fetch();
$User_Chk->close();

if ($User_Chk === 1){

    $Query = $this->_Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password,Salt,UserStatus FROM users WHERE Username=?");
    $Query->bind_param('s',$Username);
    $Query->execute();
    $Query->bind_result($User_ID,$Username,$User_Password,$User_Salt,$User_Status);
    $Query->fetch();
    $Query->close();
    return array(
                "UserID" => $User_ID,
                "Username" => $Username,
                "Password" => $User_Password,
                "Salt" => $User_Salt,
                "Status" => $User_Status
            );  

}
return false;
```

But.. As i've always followed the rule of let MySQL do the work before PHP has to manipulate.. To be frank, i'm not that savvy with MySQL Queries/Keywords.. So, is there any built in function to join the two queries & manipulate the returns before PHP fetches the results with the `bind_result()` function?

Comment: you have different capitalization of `username` / `Username` in the queries...

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Good spot, perhaps this  could sometimes return a true and fetch required rows, and sometimes not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Query->fetch()` should, in principle, be called in a loop, because it is in principle capable of returning zero, one, or multiple rows. The usual way of expressing that is

```
  while($Query->fetch()) {
        /* process the $row */
  }
  $Query->close();
```

It seems that your business rules (that is, uniqueness of your `username` column) means that your query can return either zero or one rows. So, you could do this effectively.

```
  if($Query->fetch()) {
      /* process the user's information */
  } else {
      /* no such user */
  }
  $Query->close();
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Using a loop to iterate through the result set would be wasted memory (I know micro but still), since there's only one row being fetched

Comment: Why would it waste memory? It would only iterate once. You're in php: the only memory involved here is dozens of bytes of language parse tree.